# How do you turn a date in SQL to text using a SELECT statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, date, datetime

I keep finding complex solutions to "similar" questions, but what I'm needing I think is much more simple.

I have a table that has "Winners" in it. Name, address, etc... and most important, the date that they won. I then want to display this on the website.

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName, Prize, Winning_Date FROM Prize_Table
ORDER BY Winning_Date DESC
```

Now the `Winning_Date` column is data type `date`.

So here's my question.

If the date is `2012-01-01`, I want to be able to display just the month, and the year... in regular text.

e.g.:

```
January, 2012
```

It would also be nice to be able to place just the month abbreviated (Jan) and the year, in two different places within span tags. Kinda like you see those little calendar icons with the month, and year... and/or date, etc.

```
JAN

2012
```

I want to make sure that I preserve the ability to order by date as well... month, year is fine.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
SELECT FirstName,
       LastName,
       Prize,
       datename(mm, Winning_Date) + ', ' + datename(yyyy, Winning_Date) AS 
FROM Prize_Table
ORDER BY Winning_Date DESC
```

Comment: Oh my gosh that was fast... I'll give it a try!

Comment: I was able to use this. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName, Prize, (DATENAME(month, Winning_Date) + ',' + DATENAME(year, Winning_Date)) AS "MonthYear"  FROM Prize_Table
ORDER BY Winning_Date DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

The Convert function will display the data as text.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

You can google to find date formatting functions or write your one using replace(),etc..

In MSSQL You can: order by something that is not in the result set.
Not all DBMS's have that capability.

Answer (score 0):

Try the `DATENAME()` function.

This will grab the name of the month, and the year as a string. So, your select statement can be altered to be like:

```
SELECT 
    FirstName, 
    LastName, 
    Prize, 
    DATENAME(month, Winning_Date) + ', ' +  DATENAME(year, Winning_Date)
FROM Prize_Table
ORDER BY 
    Winning_Date DESC
```

Ordering should still work.

Comment: This was correct as well. It wouldn't let me choose two correct answers! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the query:

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName, Prize, DATENAME(MM, Winning_Date) + ', ' + CAST(YEAR(Winning_Date)     AS VARCHAR(4)) AS [Winning_Date] FROM Prize_Table 
ORDER BY DATEPART(month,Winning_Date) DESC , DATEPART(year,Winning_Date) DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

This really depends on your sql-flavor (e.g. mysql, t-sql).

In mysql you could do something like this.

```
Select concat(winner, concat(' ', date_format(Winning_date, '%m%d%Y')))
```

In t-SQL (used in MSsql server) you  could use

```
select winner + ' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, Winning_date, 120)
```

the number in convert-function call represents the format the date is converted to.

See [here](http://www.sqlusa.com/bestpractices/datetimeconversion/) for more examples on the format.

Aaah. I didn't see the tag for sqlserver 2008. I am leaving this here for others, tough.